# what is the overflow tool in C language?

Tags: c++, c

During a interview, I was asked what kind of overflow tool in C language you used?
I do not know any tool like that.

And in C++, what kind of tool used to track the versions of c++ files?

Do anyone know about that?

Comment: Are we to assume that "overflow tool" refers to a "buffer overflow detector"?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I have no idea, for the versions track in C++, he talked about something in linux

Comment: I'd turn down the job if I were you.

Comment: @Tomalak GeretKal why? I like it, I am a newly graduated student, it is a good oppurtunity.

Comment: Because, assuming that you recall the term used verbatim, the employer doesn't seem to know what he's on about. :)

Comment: More likely, there is confusion about what got asked.   The correct response to a confusing question is, "I'm unfamiliar with that term. Can you clarify?"  If the unfamiliarity is due to a poor education, the interviewee (rightfully) loses.  If the unfamiliarity is due to a stupid employer, the interviewee loses the job, but actually wins by losing it :-}   If it is simply a local term, you get credit for knowing what to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that "overflow" in this context is referring to "buffer overflow".  There are a range of memory debuggers available, that can detect this kind of error.  One popular example is [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).

Tracking file versions is generally done with a [*revision control system*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System) (RCS), but this isn't specific to C++.  There are zillions of RCSs available, such as Sourcesafe, Perforce, ClearCase, CVS, SVN, Git, Mercurial.

Comment: I do not have working experience of C/C++, just did some course projects and homework in college, I just answer them I do not know these tools, I think they will not select me.

Comment: Should also note that version control isn't in any way specific to C++ - pretty much any software project in any language uses (or should use) it.  Probably even for school work.  It can also be used for non-software files (images, documents, data, tools) that need to be revised and have those revisions tracked.

Comment: but I was working in a company and doing my internship there, there did not use any version control tool

Comment: @ratzip - it's amazing how often I hear things like that, especially since there are many great free options for version control.

Comment: Its no loss to not work at place that doesn't use version control.

Answer (score 4):

The term is non-specific. A buffer overflow tool? A value overflow tool? What? Either your interviewer was off track, or perhaps you don't recall the exact term he used.

I even tried Googling the term and it's clearly not a generally accepted one.